# Django admin current file path

Tags: django

I can upload files in a section in admin panel.

in models.py

```
file = models.FileField(verbose_name="Upload",upload_to='static/teaching/')
```

when I want to see this file it goes like this;
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/teaching/teaching/1/change/static/teaching/Ads%C4%B1z.png`

I want it to go like this;
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/teaching/Ads%C4%B1z.png`

How can I fix this?
[image]

Comment: the image file : https://i.ibb.co/k5hDVv5/Ads-z.png

Comment: This won't go into the *static* folder you need to add only *teacher* folder at static folder level. Then this will work.